# EF Core add multiple entities to IdentityDBContext with aspnetUser table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a IdentityDBContext which i would like to join to other entities via EF Core.

Currently i am using the default authentication from the project creation.

I am trying to figure out how i would join the id from the aspnetUsers table into multiple custom tables.

Below URL only explains how to add it to one table, but not many tables.

[Entity Framework Core Join identity AspNetUser table. AspNetUser Id to custom tables/Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113050/entity-framework-core-join-identity-aspnetuser-table-aspnetuser-id-to-custom-ta)

Example:

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int amountQuantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
        -- userid from aspnetuserid
    }
public class TestModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string mysex { get; set; }
-- userid from aspnetuserid

    }
public class WorkOutItems
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public int CountOfItemName { get; set; }
-- userid from aspnetuserid

    }
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; } -- this to have aspnetuserid
        public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }-- this to have aspnetuserid
        public DbSet<WorkOutItems> WorkOutItems { get; set; }-- this to have aspnetuserid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was just like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<TestModel> UserAddresses { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
        public ICollection<WorkOutItems> WorkOutItems { get; set; }

    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b => { b.HasMany(p => p.UserAddresses); });
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b => { b.HasMany(p => p.Inventory); });
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b => { b.HasMany(p => p.WorkOutItems); });

        }
```